# git add . is adding everything that is in the directory even when it is specified in gitignore

Tags: git

When I run `git add .` it is adding all the files in the directory, even I specified it in `.gitignore` to ignore the specific folder and files. In this case it is the `__venv__` and `__pycache`. The `.gitignore` file is created and directories to ignore is specified before the git repository is initiated. I deleted the `git` folder and reinitiated the repository several time from the root directory of the project but it still do not ignore the declarations in the `.gitignore` file. On Windows, deleting and reinitiating the repository fixes the problem but on Linux it doesn't

Update: Adding the directory to be excluded to .git/info/exclude works but when adding it to .gitignore it doesn't

Comment: Are any files in the __pycache directory already committed into your repo?

Comment: No. I just realized that my text editor for some reason append a space in front of the declarations automatically. I found that out after clearing the file and rewrite  it again.

Comment: If you accidentally entered a space at the beginning of one line, most text editors will happily use that as the indentation for all following lines. This is a great feature because it is often what we want when writing code. All of the lines inside a function should be indented the same, for example. Sounds like you found a situation where this feature wasn't very helpful.

Comment: Yea, I didn't even realized I tapped the space bar, it's pretty useful though but in situations like this it is hard to find.

Comment: I am sure we're talking about Python so the correct name of the directory is `__pycache__` (double underscores at the front and back).

Comment: yea and that's the one I entered.

Answer (score 3):

The rule to add in a .gitignore should be:

```
__venv__/
__pycache/
# or
__pycache__/
```

(see https://www.gitignore.io/api/python)

Note the trailing '`/`'

> I just realized that my text editor for some reason append a space in front of the declarations automatically.
>   I found that out after clearing the file and rewrite it again

That would explain why a `.gitignore` rule is not applied indeed.

If the files within those two folders were not already tracked, they won't be added.
If not:

```
git rm --cached -r __venv__/
```